# How to display an Android activity mockup in Java?

Tags: java, android

I've been tasked with finding a way to create and display a mockup of an Android activity from within a Java application. The goal is to allow a user to change some options and see how they will look on our Android devices. My gut reaction is that this is infeasible, but maybe a library exists to emulate an android activity based on xml resources or something along those lines. Are there any existing solutions for this type of thing? It doesn't have to be written *in Java* as long as I can somehow call the tool from Java and display the result (show an image, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

There are serveral tools online to do these sort of jobs, take a look to [Zepelin](https://zeplin.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'emulate an android activity', but you can certainly mock up an activity in Android Studio by setting up the XML file how you would want the activity to look and activating buttons etc from the java. Is this what you mean?

You could make an extra simple activity to display the activities, i.e. if you want to show different backgrounds, you could have a button and imageView set up in the xml, and the button in java, with all of the images of the backgrounds in a folder and each time the button is pressed a new background is shown in the imageView.

Comment: The problem is that this needs to be integrated with an existing Java application. Basically, we have a Java application and an Android app. The Android app has a particular activity with custom layouts, etc. Somehow I need to emulate the *appearance* of the Android activity within the Java application as though it were actually running on an Android device.

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2141484 this shows how to convert a Java program to an android app. Maybe this is the solution you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Basically, our Java program outputs a configuration file which the Android app uses to set up its appearance. Users change settings in our Java program, export the configuration file, and then load this file into our app. I need to show a preview of what the app screens will look like within the Java application, so the user doesn't have to go through the whole process of exporting and loading the configuration file if they want to see a change.